# Animation snaps

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a character that has an idle or walk animation that is looped. On a different layer I play a shoot animation (with AddMixingTransform). I use an event in my input manager that sends a signal to my WeaponAnimation script to start playing the shoot animation. It is a looped animation. And when I recieve my stop shoot signal I set the WrapMode to once and I do an Animation.Blend to weight 0 with the remaining time of the shoot animation.

When I shoot and release my mouse immediately it plays the animation until end with a smooth blending to my idle animation. But when I release my mouse after it has looped, the animation snaps to the idle animation with no blending.

I tried to use an AnimationEvent at the end of the animation that would call up my EndAnim function and it checked if my wrapMode was ClampForever, then it blends to weight 0 and stops the animation after the blend is done. This results in the same behavior.

Can anyone figure out what is going wrong?

If you want some code, ask it which part. Because I don't want to post the entire scripts, that would be very long ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seams you are doing a lot of manual work to blend these animations.

You can use unity's built in cross fade.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.CrossFade.html